# Do I need to include the licence for part of a program, which I have modified?

Tags: mit, derivative-works, law, source-code

The X window manager `dwm` is designed to be customised by copying its default configuration `config.def.h` (which is supplied, along with the program's source code, under the MIT/X consortium licence) into `config.h` and then editing `config.h`.

I have uploaded a custom `config.h` to a GitLab repository I own which I'm using for config files and the like ('dotfiles'). This file was created in the manner described above, but I did not include `config.def.h` in my repository.

The MIT licence states that

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
>   all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

Do I need to include the MIT licence with `config.h` in the repository?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the license applies to the header as well. The easiest way to satisfy the license terms is to copy the project's MIT license directly into a comment block in your modified header file. You only have to include the license notice, but are not required to publish your modifications or your dotfiles under the MIT license.